# how to find time difference between two tables column?

Tags: sql, oracle

i have two tables having same column name and find the difference between them ?

class_time (column name) from class_time(parent table)

```
0200AM
0230AM
0300AM
0330AM
0400AM
0430AM
0500AM
0530AM
```

class_time (column name) from class_period(child table)

```
0330AM
0200AM:0230AM:0300AM
```

the difference between them as i want will be as

```
0400AM
0430AM
0500AM
0530AM
```

i have tried this query but this query only subtract 0330AM because 0330AM without colon separated

```
Select main.Class_time
from (
Select class_time from class_time where class_uid=:P216_CLASS_UID
)main
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
select distinct  trim(regexp_substr(class_time,'[^:]+', 1, level) ) class_time, level
  from class_period where class_uid=:P216_CLASS_UID 
  and class_time=main.Class_time
   connect by regexp_substr(class_time, '[^:]+', 1, level) is not null
);
```

Comment: I bet this question could be made more clear. Based on the format of the data above, it seems you are after some sort of recursive scan, however, there are no keys or schema provided that would give anyone reading this a meaningful way to answer your question.

Comment: and you could share what you have tried so far to solve the problem.

Comment: please see me code i have tried , i have updated my question

Comment: [edit] your question and post the names of the columns and their data types for database table `class_time` and table `class_period`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By seeing the sample value and your attempt, i assume the `class_time`(Column) is of `VARCHAR` datatype. In that case, you can achieve this using `NOT IN`. Check the below query.

```
SELECT * FROM parent_table 
WHERE  class_time NOT IN (SELECT Regexp_substr(class_time, '[^:]+', 1, LEVEL) AS class_time 
                          FROM   child_table 
                          CONNECT BY Regexp_substr(class_time, '[^:]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL) 
ORDER  BY class_time;
```

[**CHECK DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8e50f88262e510968c54ba6496ce5613)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the difference in above case using following two steps:

1) create a stored procedure to explode and store colon (:) separated records in a temp table:

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE PROCEDURE explode( pDelim VARCHAR(32), pStr TEXT)    BEGIN
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_explode;
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_explode (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, word VARCHAR(40));
  SET @sql := CONCAT('INSERT INTO temp_explode (word) VALUES (', REPLACE(QUOTE(pStr), pDelim, '\'), (\''), ')');
  PREPARE myStmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE myStmt;
END |

DELIMITER ;
```

2) then select exploded class times from child table:

```
SET @str  = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(class_time SEPARATOR ':') FROM class_period); 
SET @delim = ":"; 

CALL explode(@delim,@str);
SELECT word FROM temp_explode;
```

Now you can replace class_period with temp_explode and class_period.class_time with temp_explode.word in your query

Comment: This is Mysql solution while OP needs Oracle solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question then you are looking at minus

```
With a as 
(Select '0200AM' col From dual union all
 Select '0230AM' From dual union all
 Select '0300AM' From dual union all
 Select '0330AM' From dual union all
 Select '0400AM' From dual union all
 Select '0430AM' From dual union all
 Select '0500AM' From dual union all
 Select '0530AM' From dual 
)
, b as 
 (Select '0330AM' col From dual union all
  Select '0200AM' From dual union all
  Select '0230AM' From dual union all
  Select '0300AM' From dual
 )
Select * from a
minus 
Select * from b
```

Output

```
 COL   
------
0400AM
0430AM
0500AM
0530AM
```